What happens to stock bought in banks in case of bankruptcy?
There is a Bank Guarantee Fund (in Poland, and similar stuff in other countries) which protects up to 100 000 EUR in case of bank problems, i.e. going bankrupt. Now, there are banks which offer brokerage accounts and allow investing in stocks.
I have some questions here:

Are stocks owned through these brokerage accounts, i.e. in Revolut, my ownership? Or are their owned by Revolut?
If bank goes bankrupt (or is closed due to other reasons), and I have 50.000 EUR in free money available in account and 100.000 EUR in stocks, how much is covered by Bank Guarantee Fund? Do I get:


50.000 EUR back due to the Fund and stocks are lost?
100.000 EUR total, 50.000 EUR available and 50.000 EUR due to loss of stocks?
50.000 EUR back due to the fund and stocks are transferred to another broker?


Also what happens if I invest through broker who is not a bank, i.e. XTB?


Not very familiar with Polish law, but there's the EU Directive 97/9/EC that Poland is required to implement.

In the US, banks are required to keep client money separate from the bank's money. So, absent fraud, bankruptcy doesn't affect client accounts.
